# How to create excel file with multiple sheet name based on modules?

Tags: datatable, ado.net, dataset, openxml, c#-5.0

I work on c# desktop app I Can't  export data to excel file with multiple tab(multi sheet).

only that i can do create excel file with only sheet based on data exist on data table module field.

I use open XML library

Data table data as below :

Divide Output Excel File To Multi Tab based On Module

```
PartId  Company Files   Tab     Module  
1222    micro   Abc     source     1    
1321    silicon Abc     source     1    
1444    cd2     Abc     types      2    
1321    cd3     Abc     types      2    
1541    tvs     Abc     types      2
```

Expected Result :

Create File ABC.xlsx with two sheet first sheet name source and second sheet name types based on module and load data related to every sheet based on data exist on data table.

so if I have two modules meaning I have two sheet .

What I have tried:

```
public Boolean createExcelFile(DataTable Table,String FullFilePathName)
      {
          Boolean IsDone = false;
          try
          {
              FileInfo CreatedFile = new FileInfo(FullFilePathName);
              Boolean ISNew = false;
              if (!CreatedFile.Exists)
              {

                  ISNew = true;
              }
              using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(CreatedFile))
              {
                  ExcelWorksheet ws;
                  if (ISNew == true)
                  {
                      ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet");




                      ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromDataTable(Table, ISNew, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light8);
                  }

                  else
                  {
                       ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
                       ws.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromDataTable(Table, ISNew);
                  }
                  pck.Save();
                  IsDone = true;

              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {

              throw ex;
          }
          return IsDone;
      }
```

but problem code above create one files with one sheet only

so How to create file with multi sheet based on module ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/spreadsheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by store multi data table on datasets then loop on it

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        var result = from rows in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                     group rows by new { Module = rows["ModuleName"] } into grp
                                     select grp;
                        foreach (var item in result)
                        {
                            ds.Tables.Add(item.CopyToDataTable());
                        }
Affected = new CExcel().createExcelFileForDs(ds, exportPath);

 public Boolean createExcelFileForDs(DataSet ds, String FullFilePathName)
        {
            Boolean IsDone = false;
            try
            {
                FileInfo CreatedFile = new FileInfo(FullFilePathName);
                Boolean ISNew = false;
                if (!CreatedFile.Exists)
                {

                    ISNew = true;
                }
                using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(CreatedFile))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet ws;
                    foreach (DataTable Table in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        if (ISNew == true)
                        {
                            ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(Convert.ToString(Table.Rows[0]["Tab name"]));
                            ws.Cells.Style.Font.Size = 11; //Default font size for whole sheet
                            ws.Cells.Style.Font.Name = "Calibri"; //Default Font name for whole sheet    
                            if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft)   // Right to Left for Arabic lang
                            {
                                ExcelWorksheetView wv = ws.View;
                                wv.ZoomScale = 100;
                                wv.RightToLeft = true;
                                ws.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
                                ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ExcelWorksheetView wv = ws.View;
                                wv.ZoomScale = 100;
                                wv.RightToLeft = false;
                                ws.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
                                ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
                            }
                            ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
                            ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromDataTable(Table, ISNew, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light8);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
                            ws.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromDataTable(Table, ISNew);
                        }
                    }
                    pck.Save();
                    IsDone = true;



                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            return IsDone;
        }
```